# Laravel Links always lead to the index page

Tags: php, laravel, web

I have the following links in the header page:

```
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('root') }}">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('about')}}">About</a>
   </li> 
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact') }}">Contact</a>
   </li>
```

And I have the following routes in web.php

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
})->name('root');
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{locale}','middleware'=>'setLocale'],function(){
    Route::get('/',[FrontEndController::class, 'index'])->name('index');

  
});


Route::get('/about',function(){
    return view('about');
})->name('about');
Route::get('/contact',function(){
    return view('contact');
})->name('contact');
```

the problem is whenever i click a link i go to the index page, in spite of the path in the url is correct.

Note: whenever I remove the Route::group, the links work properly.

please help...

Comment: Try moving the second route (the one within the Route::group) to the end.

Comment: I tried it didn't work @KennyHorna

Comment: have you tried `php artisan route:clear` && `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: yes but it didn't work @MuhammadAnas

Comment: i guess {locale} will match anything here, try to use the Route::pattern function : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#parameters-global-constraints Something like Route::pattern('locale', '[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}') should work for a locale that looks like en-us or en-gb

Comment: Thanks, I added a regular expression for local and it works:Route::group(['prefix'=>'{locale}','where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],'middleware'=>'setLocale'],function(){

Answer (score 1):

You need to put all Routes under locale (not only home page), else it will consider that `/about` & `/contact` on the URLs are locales also, then redirect you to the home page.

For your example, you should do something like :

```
Route::get('/',function(){
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{locale}','middleware'=>'setLocale'],function(){
    Route::get('/',[FrontEndController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::get('/about',function(){ return view('about');})->name('about');
    Route::get('/contact',function(){ return view('contact');})->name('contact');
});
```

No need to name `root` Route, you should use `index` for home page.

Answer (score 0):

This 'prefix'=>'{locale}' is dynamic, anything you put in the url is going here.
You need to rethink about the locale URL.

This will work fine

'prefix'=>'xyz/{locale}'

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding regular expression for locale:

Route::group(['prefix'=>'{locale}','where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],'middleware'=>'setLocale'],function(){